# Implementing an options dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

in my application i want to implement an options dialog like you have in VisualStudios if you go to Tools->Options in the menubar. How can i do this? My first idea was to use pages and navigation but maybe there's an easier approach?

Comment: Since you are using WPF, are you using any of the MVVM approaches to build your application?

Comment: Yes, i use the mvvm pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the *easiest* way but I wrote this snippet that match your goal and it's a good exercise.

In an empty Windows Forms project add a ListBox (listBox1) and a Panel (panel1). Then create 2 UserControls (UserControl1 and UserControl2), these will be the content that is shown when you click the list.

In your Form1 class we create a `ListItem` class that will contain your menu options as such:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public UserControl Value { get; set; }

        public ListItem(string text, UserControl value)
        {
            Text = text;
            Value = value;
        }
    };

    ...

}
```

After that you add items to the ListBox right after InitializeComponent() in Form1:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item1", new UserControl1()));
    listBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item2", new UserControl2()));
}
```

This will make it so when you use listBox1.SelectedItem it will return an object that you can cast to a ListItem and access the associated UserControl.

To make use of this behaviour, go to designmode and double-click the ListBox, this'll add code for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event. We use this event to display the UserControl in the Panel `panel1`. This will clear any old Panel content and add a selected UserControl:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    UserControl control = (listBox1.SelectedItem as ListItem).Value;
    if(control != null)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Add(control);
        control.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
}
```

I suggest you try adding a button or something to differentiate the UserControls and play around. Have fun! :)

Comment: In the meantime I've decided to use a tabControl. But your approach sounds good nontheless. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new Window and show that as opposed to create a page and navigate to it. Then you would call `.show()` on the new window for it to show.

Then you would change the look of the new window to however you want, the same as editing pages.

[image: Add New Item Window]

Answer (score 0):

If you build your options into a full object model that matches the structure of the options window, then the best way is to use whatever navigation-aware UI binding that your MVVM toolkit uses. The options window would start off as a new root level window to which you would bind the root of your options data model.

So, in short think of the options dialog as a mini-application that uses the same structure as your main MVVM application, but with a different data model root.

If you plan to allow the user to cancel the changes to the options, then you would want your options data model to be clonable so that you can populate the options window with the clone and then swap out the real options with the new data if the user presses OK on the options window.  If they select cancel you can just throw the cloned object away and destroy the window.

Comment: The user should be able to cancle the changes. What do you mean with "... data model [...] exist as an in-memory representation ..."? The only way i see is to deep copy the whole data model, make the changes and deep copy it back if the user accepts the changes.

Comment: Changed the wording on that final part to be more clear about my meaning.  The other path would be if your options were permanently stored somehow, like in a database, and re-read as needed.

Comment: If i implement IClonable i have to implement it in each custom typed object of my options data model right? Because i have a lot custom typed objects and collections of them in the data model, is there an easy way to clone the whole data model?

Comment: You can use AutoMapper and just map each object onto itself if you don't want to write the code for implementing IClonable